# How to remove text from NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to remove some text from NSMutableAttributedString.

My code looks like this:

```
[attributedLabel setText:string afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString)
    {
        NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mutableAttributedString length]);
        NSRegularExpression *regexp = ParenthesisRegularExpression();
        UIFont *italicSystemFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:Size];
        DLog(@"%@",italicSystemFont.fontName);
        CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)italicSystemFont.fontName, italicSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
        [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:[mutableAttributedString string] options:0 range:stringRange usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
            if (italicFont) {
                [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName range:result.range];
                [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)italicFont range:result.range];
                CFRelease(italicFont);
            }
        }];

        return mutableAttributedString;
    }];
```

I would like to remove the parentheses from this mutableAttributedString.

Tried this:

```
[[attributedLabel.attributedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
```

But there is

```
no visible interface in NSAttributedString for stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString.
```

How to I remove text from NSMutableAttributedString?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even assume that `NSMutableAttributedString` responds to messages `NSMutableString` responds to? They don't inherit from one another. Instead you should read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000169-mutableString) and use the `mutableString` method to get a mutable string instance to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string` method to return an `NSString*` from an `NSAttributedString`.

```
 NSString *newString = [attributedLabel.attributedText string];
```

Then you can use the normal NSString or NSMutableString methods on the resultant string and assign it back to your `NSAttributedString` when complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *source = attributedLabel.attributedText;
UIFont *italicSystemFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:Size];

    CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)italicSystemFont.fontName, italicSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);

[[source  copy] enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, source.length) options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationReverse  usingBlock:^(NSDictionary* attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([[attrs valueForKey:kCTFontAttributeName] isEqualTo:(__bridge id)italicFont]) {
        [source deleteCharactersInRange:range];
    }

}];
```